# Create a GiST index on `segmentby` columns compressed by timescaledb

Tags: timescaledb

When compressing a hypertable with a `segmentby` clause timescaledb creates a b-tree on the `segmentby` columns ([documentation](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/compression)):

> In fact, for even more efficient access, we build b-tree indexes over
> each segmentby column.

However, I need to segment by a `cidr` column, which b-trees don't fully support. Specifically, there's no support for the `>>` and `<<` operators on `cidr`. Is there a way to make the `segmentby` create a GiST index?